# CosmosDb Mongo - collection with shardkey, slow query by shardkey?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I have a CosmosDb collection with Mongodb.
This is a customer database, and the ShardKey is actually CustomerId.
My collection has 200000 records, and has an combined index of both e-mail and customerid.

An example of a customer:

```
{
"CustomerId" : "6a0f4360-d722-4926-9751-9c7fe6a97cb3",
"FirstName" : "This is my company first name",
"LastName" : "This is my company last name",
"Email" : "6a0f4360-d722-4926-9751-9c7fe6a97cb3@somemail.com",
"Addresses" : [
    {
        "AddressId" : "54e34da9-55fb-4d60-8411-107985c7382e",
        "Door" : "11111",
        "Floor" : "99",
        "Side" : "B",
        "ZipCode" : "8888",
    }
]
```

}

What I find strange is if I query by Email it spends 7000RUs (which is too much - at least is what data explorer tells me...) but if I query by CustomerId, it spends more or less the same RUs...

My questions are:

- Shoudn't both operations spend less RUs than this, specially by CustomerId?

An example of a query by E-mail:

```
{ "Email" : { $eq: "3f7da6c3-81bd-4b1d-bfa9-d325388079ab@somemail.com" } }
```

An example of a query by CustomerId:

```
{ "CustomerId" : { $eq: "3f7da6c3-81bd-4b1d-bfa9-d325388079ab" } }
```

Another question, my index contains both Email and CustomerId. Is there any way for me to query by e-mail and return only CustomerId, for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Shoudn't both operations spend less RUs than this, specially by CustomerId?

`CustomerId` is your shard key (aka partition key) which helps in grouping documents with same value of CustomerId to be stored in the same logical partition. This grouping is used during pin-point GET/SET calls to Cosmos but not during querying. So, you would need an index on `CustomerId` explicitly.

Furthermore, since the index that you have is a composite index on `CustomerId` and `Email`, doing a query on only one of these fields at a time will lead to a scan being performed in order to get back the result. Hence the high RU charge and the similar amount of RU charge on each of these queries.

> Another question, my index contains both Email and CustomerId. Is there any way for me to query by e-mail and return only CustomerId, for example?

Firstly, in order to query optimally on `Email`, you would need to create an index on `Email` separately. Thereafter, you may use the [`project` feature of Mongo](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/) to include only certain fields in the response.

Something like this-

`find({ "Email" : { $eq: "3f7da6c3-81bd-4b1d-bfa9-d325388079ab@somemail.com" } }, { "CustomerId":1 })`